# Forem forum software in Docker can't be reached from Nginx in Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, docker

I am trying to run the Forem forum software in Docker via Dokku. I was following this guide: https://dev.to/akhilnaidu/self-hosting-forem-dev-on-linux-using-t2d-2kgh

The A record of the domain evstalkin.com is pointing to the IP address of the VPS.

Now there are two Docker containers running on my VPS (Ubuntu 22.04, Afterburst.com) and an error message is displayed in browser. ("We're sorry, but something went wrong." and it has fancier CSS than usual nginx error messages, so I think it comes from the configuration done by the t2d script.)

/var/log/nginx/nforem-error.log says:

```
2024/02/01 14:09:20 [error] 177919#177919: *1449 connect() failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: 94.113.160.209, server: evstalkin.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.5:5000/", host: "evstalkin.com"
```

and 'docker ps' says:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS      NAMES
5df9cfa0ef53   dokku/nforem:latest   "/start sidekiq_work…"   2 days ago   Up 2 days              nforem.sidekiq_worker.1
6217bf35a442   dokku/oforem:latest   "/start sidekiq_work…"   2 days ago   Up 2 days              oforem.sidekiq_worker.1
ffab6be18567   redis:7.2.4           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago   Up 2 days   6379/tcp   dokku.redis.redisdb
54678f0806cd   postgres:16.1         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago   Up 2 days   5432/tcp   dokku.postgres.foremdb
```

so I think that nginx can't talk to the Forem containers because they don't expose any ports.

I looked at some other things but couldn't find anything that looks like a misconfiguration.

```
# grep -R 172.17.0.5 /home/dokku/*
/home/dokku/nforem/IP.sidekiq_worker.1:172.17.0.5
/home/dokku/nforem/IP.web.1:172.17.0.5
/home/dokku/nforem/nginx.conf:  server 172.17.0.5:5000;

# cat /home/dokku/nforem/nginx.conf

server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name evstalkin.com; 
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/nforem-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/nforem-error.log;

  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/wasm application/json application/xml application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://nforem-5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;
    proxy_buffer_size 4096;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffers 8 4096;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 8192;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
    
  }

  

  error_page 400 401 402 403 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 /400-error.html;
  location /400-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 404 /404-error.html;
  location /404-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 /500-error.html;
  location /500-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }
  include /home/dokku/nforem/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;

}

upstream nforem-5000 {

  server 172.17.0.5:5000;
}


# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      686/nginx: master p 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      655/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      581/systemd-resolve 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      686/nginx: master p 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      655/sshd: /usr/sbin 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           581/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 209.222.17.233:68       0.0.0.0:*                           579/systemd-network
```

How do I find out, what is necessary to configure? Thank you very much.
bhy

Comment: Check the logs of your container using `docker logs`

Comment: Your container does not have published any ports.

Comment: I would try network mode host to connet the docker container to the host. Otherwise docker creates it own network which is not reachable from the host. `network_mode: host`

Comment: host network mode should only be used for special setups. publishing the port should be completely sufficient.

Comment: host network mode removes container network isolation and exposes all software running in the containers to the internet. Don't enable it unless you have configured your firewall appropriately. It is also going to cause port conflicts if different containers run software on the same ports, like possibly `sidekiq` instances in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Forem seems to have a docker compose which publishes the ports I would run that first

https://github.com/forem/forem/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

Comment: This docker-compose is intended for local development, publishes only 3000 port and even includes Chrome browser.